# Creating a RethinkDB cluster on Amazon ECS

Tags: rethinkdb, amazon-ecs

I am using the official Docker image for RethinkDB.  I am trying to use AWS EC2 Container Services to create a RethinkDB cluster.  I can easily get stand alone instances to run, but have had no luck creating a RethinkDB cluster.

I have tried various security group settings.  I even made everything wide open, but no luck.  When I launch the Docker image, I pass in `--bind all` and `--join [ip]:29015`, but nothing.

Has anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default networking for docker on amazon ECS is the docker0 bridge. This means multiple containers on the same EC2 instance can talk to each other through the bridge but not to other EC2 instances and containers across the ECS cluster.

You could set the networkMode in your task definition to 'host' which should then let you use the network on your EC2 instances directly and use the security groups you have defined See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#network_mode.

The alternative is to setup an overlay network using something like flannel, weave, openvswitch etc. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/architecting-microservices-using-weave-net-and-amazon-ec2-container-service/ for an example using weave.